# 2002 Hyundai Accent not charging battery

Tags: battery, alternator, hyundai, accent

Hyundai Accent battery will not charge.
Had battery tested, bad, replaced.
Had alternator tested, bad, replaced.

I installed the alternator myself, from what I remember it was connected by two plugs, and a belt and those were assembled as I remembered taking them off. 
Is there supposed to be 3 plugs, a ground or something?

Front headlights also wont work and I've checked all my < 30 watt fuses, all good.
I'm about to replace my battery connectors but I don't think is the problem.
Belt is not squeaking and seems to be running fine.

I cannot get my headlights to work or my battery to charge.
My question is did I install my alternator right, and why is it not charging?
Bonus question : Could one of those bigger fuses being blown be the culprit to both my problems?

Answer (score 2):

There was a > 30 fuse blown. Replaced that and tightened battery connectors. 
Also fuse under the steering wheel was blown. Fixed that, and I had headlights.
Battery seems to be charging now.

Check your fuses, I checked them and missed some blown ones.